# Android: Using application resources

Tags: android, resources, bitmap

I'm making a tile game. My application has an object (GraphicEngine) that handles all of the graphical operations. Each character in the game is its own object. When a character wants something drawn it sends an object (a package of sorts) to the GraphicEngine object. The GraphicEngine object stores this package in an ArrayList. Each of these packages contain x and y coordinates and a bitmap image. When the time comes GraphicEngine draws the whole list to a single bitmap and displays it.

I have programmed this, but I don't know how to get a `png image` from my resources folder and turn it into a `bitmap`. I can't find help anywhere which makes me think I'm mis-understanding the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Call `getResources()` on an `Activity` to get a `Resources` object.

Step #2: Call `getDrawable()` on the `Resources` to get a `Drawable` for your desired resource ID.

Step #3: Have the `Drawable` draw itself onto the `Canvas` via `draw()`.

You do not "turn it into a bitmap" normally. In a pinch, I think you can get a bitmap-backed `Canvas` and have the `Drawable` draw to it. However, that would be inefficient, AFAICT, compared to having the `Drawable` draw correctly in the first place.